# Streaming RTSP through a raspberry pi with gstreamer. unable to get audio out

Tags: video, gstreamer, rtsp, amazon-kinesis

So I'm using gstreamer on a raspberry pi to pull an RTSP stream from a camera on the local network and then pushing the content to amazon kinesis.  The video works but audio is missing.

I know the rtsp stream has audio as I can view it directly from the IP camera with VLC.  But when it goes through the streamer the audio is stripped. In trying to test it I am sending the content to a file with filesink. The file is created but has video only. no audio.

```
gst-launch-1.0  -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://Test:Test@192.168.1.18/live" short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, format=avc,alignment=au ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=./file.mp4
```

I tried something I found on stackoverflow but it doesn't work. When I try and end the stream it hangs indefinitely on "waiting for EOS..." and when I try and stop it again it stops but the output file is of size 0.

```
gst-launch-1.0  -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://Test:Test@192.168.1.18/live" short-header=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, format=avc,alignment=au ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=./file.mp4
```

The actual kinesis command I'm trying to enable is this.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.1.10/live"  ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! kvssink <some additional kinesis parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working.

This is what it takes to include alaw audio source on a raspberry pi.

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc name=src location="rtsp://Pass:Word@192.168.1.22/live" short-header=true do-timestamp=true ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! kvssink name=sink stream-name="name" access-key="key" secret-key="secret aws-region="region" frame-timecodes=false src. ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! sink.
```